# Accessing S3 with AWS Java SDK and STS token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a java spring boot app that is running in Kubernetes container and that container has STS token which expires every hour (exact time is unknown).

Once I create S3 client, it's using WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider to read token and populate credentials, however, I don't see a way to refresh those credentials at runtime once sts token has expired and credentials are no longer valid.

of course, I can create a new S3 client for every call to S3, but that's not a feasible solution
(assuming I need to run through 10K requests in a loop and pull data from S3 for all of them)
WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider  refresh() method is not implemented/empty.
Any idea on how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the container on EKS you should checkout once the IRSA option.

In IRSA you use the IAM Role with Kubernetes service account and attach that Service account to Deployment or POD which will authenticate and get the creds and your SDK will be able to access the S3.

Example or reference : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/

Very simple and basic example : https://faun.pub/rbac-irsa-in-aws-eks-2a6a86d3f756